# image from [3,M,N] to [M,N,3]

Tags: numpy

I have a ndarray representing an image with different channels like this:

image = (8,100,100) where 8=channels, 100x100 the actual image per channel

I am interested in extracting the RGB components of that image:

```
imageRGB = np.take(image, [4,2,1], axis = 0)
```

in this way I have an array of (3,100,100) with the RGB components.
However, I need to visualize it so I need an array of (100,100,3), I think it's quite straightforward to do it but I all the methods I try do not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

numpy einsum is a good tool to be used.
Official document: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html

```py
import numpy as np

imageRGB = np.random.randint(0,5,size=(3,100,101)) 
# set the last dim to 101 just to make stuff more clear
imageRGB.shape
# (3,100,101)

imageRGB_reshape = np.einsum('kij->ijk',imageRGB)
imageRGB_reshape.shape
# (100,101,3)
```

In my opinion it's the most clear way to write and read.

Answer (score 0):

Wow thank you! I have never thought to use Einstein summation, actually it works very well.

Just for curiosity is it possible to build it manually?
For example:

```
R = image[4,:,:]
G = image[2,:,:]
B = image[1,:,:]
imageRGB = ???
```

Comment: from your `8x100x100` array `image`: `image.transpose(1,2,0)[...,[4,2,1]]`